# angular.js simple function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used to have controller in whole `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">`, where I had some basic functions like this one:

```
$scope.isActive = function(route) {
    return route === $location.path();
};
```

Used here:

```
 ng-class="{active:isActive('{{ $link['url'] }}')}"
```

What's best way how to handle that? It's used in many times on different lists. Should I make a directive?

Comment: you can use  ui-sref-active..

Comment: Why you confusing this much???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you handle re-occurring functions with services ([tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11)), like this:

```
angular.module('yourAppName').service('yourServiceName', function(){
        return {
            isActive: function (route){
                return route === $location.path();
            },
});
```

Then, in your controller, add a dependency on `'yourServiceName'` and call `yourServiceName.isActive(route)` anytime you want to use it.

Comment: Aside from the general point you make in your answer, I think this is exactly what he means. If I understand correctly, he asks how to handle reoccuring functions and you answered that. JqueryKing's answer is about changing syntax, but I don't think the syntax was a problem in his case.

Comment: JqueryKing's answer is useless for me because my syntax also works. I was asking how to handle that situation without needing some controller work. Generally how to add class to a link in active route

Comment: Do you have the solution you need or is there something I can clarify for you? Let me know if you need more tutorial links/clarification. I edited to remove the "other answers" part.

Comment: Service is probably not that what I need for this. I have plenty of links <a href="/#/something">something</a> and I wanna add there active class if current url is something

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

I am pretty sure ng-class is the second part of what you need (for assigning classes based on conditions). Let me think about this for a second and then I will update the answer.

Comment: @dontHaveName: I thought about it, basically a directive isn't a bad idea now that I understand what you are trying to do fully. The exact how would take a little bit to write though. You should be able to handle it fairly easily as long as you know how to isolate your directive scope and pass attributes from the parent controller. If not, I will try to check in this evening. No promises though.

Comment: It's okay I will figure out some solution on my own but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ng-class="{active:isActive('{{ $link['url'] }}')}"
```

to

```
ng-class="{'active': isActive($link['url'])}"
```